# Forge Laravel SSL Installation Issue w/ Cloudflare

Tags: laravel, cloudflare, laravel-6, laravel-forge

I just migrated over to Cloudflare and got an API Token created with Read permissions to SSL/Certificates.

I'm using Forge.Laravel for deployment.

Previously, I had SSL working with certbot.

I removed those SSL certs and tried installing with the automated Forge Laravel method for Cloudflare.

This is what I got:

```
Resolving forge-certificates.laravel.com (forge-certificates.laravel.com)... 104.26.13.100, 104.26.12.100, 2606:4700:20::681a:c64, ...
Connecting to forge-certificates.laravel.com (forge-certificates.laravel.com)|104.26.13.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘letsencrypt_script1578692817’

     0K ..                                                     19.5M=0s

2020-01-10 21:46:57 (19.5 MB/s) - ‘letsencrypt_script1578692817’ saved [2701]

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-cloudflare, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
dns-01 challenge for camscott.me
dns-01 challenge for camscott.me
Unsafe permissions on credentials configuration file: letsencrypt/creds.ini
Cleaning up challenges
Error determining zone_id: 6003 Invalid request headers. Please confirm that you have supplied valid Cloudflare API credentials. (Did you copy your entire API key?)
cp: cannot stat '/etc/letsencrypt/live/certificate/privkey.pem': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/etc/letsencrypt/live/certificate/fullchain.pem': No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there are was another change. I had to create a token. From the docs that I didn't know forge had till now :)

https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/sites/ssl.html#ssl

## Cloudflare API Token

If you are using Cloudflare, your Cloudflare API token must have the Zone.Zone.Read and Zone.DNS.Edit permissions. In addition, the token must have permissions on all zones attached to your Cloudflare account.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create an API Token, rather copy your actual API key.

Solved.